# Selenium FirefoxDriver clicks on wrong link when animations occur

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

I am using Selenium 2.35 and having a unpredictable error while trying to click on an element in firefox like this:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

The element I've located is a < span > element with a click event tied to it.  The issue I am running into is occasionally when Firefox tries to click on the element is misses and clicks on an entirely different element.  If I walk through my code using the debugger the issue never occurs which leads me to believe that the FirefoxDriver is just clicking on the wrong location on the browser, having to do with a timing issue.  There are dynamically loaded < div >'s on my page that make the element I want to click shift down just before I locate it and send the .click() command.  I believe this is the source of my issue.  I can put a Thread.sleep(500) is ensure that it has enough time to finish animating and inserting the dynamic divs, but that seems sloppy to me.  Is there a way I can tell my FirefoxDriver to wait until the elements on the screen are done shifting around before it tries to send the .click() event?

Also, I have tried to send just the element.click() but that seems to fail more often.

Update (9/5/13):

The solution I came to with the help of @MrTi 's comment was the following:

```
private void jsClickOnElementById(String id)
{
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("var x = $('#" + id + "');");
    sb.append("x.click();");
    js.executeScript(sb.toString());
}
```

Just to ensure the element is actually on the page I added the initial "wait" call, and then use the JavascriptExecutor to run some jquery and click on the element on the page.  This seems to work great for my case.  If anyone has help as to some drawbacks to this solution they would be greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to the JavascriptExecutor class.

Comment: I'm getting this problem with NO animations LOL, it clicks the long element with `element.click()` in firefox marionette (works in chromedriver) but `$('#id').click()` in javascript works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that the dynamic loading is making your selector select something else.  If you post your HTML, (especially the before/after the dynamic loading) that would be immensely helpful in writing a better selector.

However, there are a couple of ways to wait until the loading is finished.

The first to wait until `(Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")` returns true.  This waits for all JQuery on the page to finish (which is probably what is causing the dynamic loading).  Its useful, but I would recomment waiting for something else.

The second option is to wait until an element that is dynamically loaded is present:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementSelectedBy(...selector...));
```

I like this method, as it will wait exactly as long as you need to wait, and no longer.

The final option is to write a selector that will always select the element, even if other stuff is going on.  This may be your best option, but you may also run into `StaleElementReferenceExceptions`.

Comment: I ended up using your JavascriptExecutor idea to select the element on the page by Id and sending the .click() event that way.  This seems to work without fail since I know all of the elements I want to click on are already loaded, I just want to make sure they are receiving the click event.

Comment: Check out my update to see my solution I came to with your JavascriptExecutor suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to ensuring that the page is actually visible with ExpectedConditions, this situation could be solved by handling animations (transitions) on page.

It's possible to disable all the animations on page, **until page is refreshed**, by executing:

```
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("$('body').append('<style> * {transition: none!important;}</style>')")
```

Also, If you know the specific element that got the animation you can check if it's animated ([JQuery animation selector)](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/):

```
(Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $("#ELEMENT_ID").is(":animated")")
```

If the specific element unknown you can determine if all animations have finished:

```
(Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $(":animated").length == 0 ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly in 2018 (five years later) I can confirm element.click() in selenium doesn't always click the right element. I still have to shell-out to jquery with JavascriptExecutor to click on an element by ID via `jquery $(selector).click()` to hit the element with confidence.

And it's NOT just that it can't find the element due to scrolls, animation, or offscreen, it appears Selenium's wrapper of Marionette's internal DOM tree is out of sync with firefox's geckodriver somehow for dynamically loaded elements (in this case a table row)